# What does actually mean by the term 'Full Object Model' in PHP?

Tags: php, object-model

I come across the following sentence from PHP Manual :

> PHP 5 has a full object model.

What does this statement actually mean?

What exactly PHP has by means of the term **'Full Object Model'**?

Reference link from the PHP Manual : [Introduction](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php#oop5.intro)

Comment: Linking where in the manual you found this would be helpful.

Comment: @WillemRenzema : I've appended the link to the body of my question. Please see the updated question body.

Answer (score 1):

The object model describes the properties of objects in a programming language. Visibility of classes/methods, encapsulation, polymorphism, inheritance, etc. Full object model means that php's object model is supporting all properties which most of the common object oriented languages have.